# Use model space coordinates

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autocad

I'm using the Forge Viewer and I'm having trouble getting the model space coordinate system instead of paper space.  I have a building floor plan in view and I can get the coordinates of things but they are all like 3.5, 4.6, etc. that would be within an 8.5x11 piece of paper so I would assume that's paper coordinates.  I really need model coordinates that should be more like 56, 75, 152, etc. (assuming it's feet).  I've tried looking for different viewables but it always seems to be paper space.  Here is my code to load a document:

```
  viewer?.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()).then(e => {
    console.log(e);
    if (viewerReady) {
      viewerReady(viewer!);
    }
  });
```

This works but I get the paper coordinates.  I did look through the name of the viewable that comes back as default and it's 'Model' so that seems like it's model space to me but the coordinates don't seem to be.  I did also open the source ACAD drawing and confirmed that in model space the coordinates are correct (one test was 345ft, etc.).

Is this something I can see in the document somewhere?  Is there a scaling of some type?  Or a parameter of some type in the conversion that I need to set?  How do I get the 'real' coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

When working with 2D drawings, you should be able to find this information in the model's metadata:

[image]

Comment: Ok so to make sure I understand, in the image here how would I translate the units?  So say the center of that lower center circle returns me a point with x,y coordinates of 3.45,1.25; how would I make that into actual model coordinates?  I see that model units are in mm here, but the logical height and plot height even in mm are far too large it seems.

Comment: Let me double-check with the engineering team, but the `Model` class provides a couple of helper methods for this, incl. `pageToModel(point1, point2, viewportId)`: https://imgur.com/a/fQa5Eh5.

Comment: Ok so I'm able to see that method and it seems to work.  However, I need to round trip this with Edit2D so I also need to be able to transform it back into page coordinates that will be accepted by Edit2D and end up in the right place.  I can't find any documentation on how I would do this.  Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that `pageToModel` accepts a 4th parameter - `inverse: bool` - that you can set to `true` to go the other way around.